# how can i get 15 cents on steam? i am just under the needed amount

Tags: steam

I need 15 cents to buy PUBG and don't know how to get it. Is there a way I can attain some money?

Comment: Use a credit card to compensate for the remainder?

Comment: You could get a job... alternatively, if you've got some Steam trading cards, you can sell those on the market and earn a couple of cents in your Steam wallet.

Comment: What on earth? Isn't this off topic?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about making money on steam, not about video games.

Answer (score 3):

Sell the cards you earn through playing games. They're usually worth around ten cents (USD) on the market, and the funds go into your Steam Wallet. (You can earn cards by simply playing the games they're associated with, up to a certain number per game; the amount depends on how many cards exist.)

Depending on the game's popularity, once you put a card on the market it should sell within a few hours.

Comment: Really? Most I see sell instantly and only go for a couple cents.

Comment: Well, YMMV; my guess is that it depends on the popularity of both the game and its trading cards, and how recently they were released.